# xdbg64 Unable to find string.. Need help cracking a program

Tags: debugging, x64dbg

Ive been trying to crack my friends program for quite some time. He gave me permission and we are trying to see if his mod menu is ready to hit the market. Ive watched a couple [youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/) and I am completely stuck.. Can anyone help me?? Would really appreciate it

When I input an incorrect password, I get this prompt.

[image]

Alternatively, I have an outdated subscription code, when I enter that code I get this prompt

[image]

After running the program through x64dbg and going to search for an associated string.. nothing comes up.. Can someone please help me?

https://gyazo.com/0853f4006a130d3922f1966b983c3970

(A Picture incase it is too small in the gif) ->

[image]

Comment: Were you able to get through this? [I'm facing a similar problem](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/32405/45039), and it'll be helpful to get a followup on this question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know x64dbg, but are you sure the string search handles wide-char strings correctly?

When do you run the search? Are you sure the strings are available at the time?

I would recommend making a deadlisting, using whatever disassembler you're comfortable with, and having a look for the strings and xrefs to them. You tend to get a very narrow view of the logic in a debugger, and you need the wide one for this.

Edit: x64dbg apparently only searches the module currently shown in the disassembly. Open up the symbols window, clickety-click your friend's module, and try searching again. Or you could set a breakpoint on MessageBox() and see where it's called.