# Need Help Cracking a Program

Tags: debugging, binary-analysis, ghidra, x64dbg, debugging-symbols

So I've got this `.exe` that I want to crack. It's an old management system for people in truck loading business.

I kind of understand what's happening with window API calls but I'm unable to access the credentials that user inputs into the form. If somehow I could get access to that input, I might be able to find where this program takes this input to check against the valid serial keys.

I've tried searching for strings, but no luck there as well.

Hoping for some guidance.

I'm using x64dbg to debug the code, and I followed couple tutorials on YouTube to get started. Most of them were easily able to crack the programs by using string search, but the strings that I want (ones in the registration window) don't show up in the search.

I've tried setting up breakpoints, but those didn't work as well.

Only thing I've seen related to the input (serial key) in the debugger so far are the values in the stack. When I start typing out the key, part of it (each of 4 characters) start appearing in the stack in this format, `L"xxxx"`. I tried checking logs, and pinpointed the thread that's responsible for carrying out registration. Last module calls that this program makes are to `CoreMessaging.dll` and `CoreUiComponents.dll`. There's also this `TextInputForm.dll`, that shows up in the stack, whenever I'm typing out the serial key.

Here are the logs:

```
Breakpoint at 0111A00A (entry breakpoint) set!
DLL Loaded: 77A80000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
DLL Loaded: 71A40000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll
DLL Loaded: 76500000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
DLL Loaded: 75F10000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll
System breakpoint reached!
DLL Loaded: 76B60000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll
DLL Loaded: 77460000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll
Thread 5744 created, Entry: ntdll.77ABCAC0, Parameter: 017E5C28
DLL Loaded: 77240000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
DLL Loaded: 76BE0000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll
DLL Loaded: 719B0000 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
DLL Loaded: 76D40000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll
DLL Loaded: 72980000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll
DLL Loaded: 719A0000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll
DLL Loaded: 6F7E0000 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
DLL Loaded: 766E0000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll
DLL Loaded: 769D0000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll
DLL Loaded: 76920000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll
DLL Loaded: 76A70000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll
DLL Loaded: 71980000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140_clr0400.dll
Thread 5732 created, Entry: ntdll.77ABCAC0, Parameter: 017E5C28
DLL Loaded: 76950000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll
DLL Loaded: 019E0000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase_clr0400.dll
DLL Loaded: 718D0000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase_clr0400.dll
DLL Loaded: 772C0000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll
DLL Unloaded: 019E0000 ucrtbase_clr0400.dll
Thread 2628 created, Entry: ntdll.77ABCAC0, Parameter: 017E5C28
DLL Loaded: 75890000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll
DLL Loaded: 76160000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll
DLL Unloaded: 76160000 combase.dll
EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO:
           dwFirstChance: 1
           ExceptionCode: 04242420 (CLRDBG_NOTIFICATION_EXCEPTION_CODE)
          ExceptionFlags: 00000000
        ExceptionAddress: kernelbase.76048D52
        NumberParameters: 3
ExceptionInformation[00]: 31415927
ExceptionInformation[01]: clr.6F7E0000
ExceptionInformation[02]: 014FF778
First chance exception on 76048D52 (04242420, CLRDBG_NOTIFICATION_EXCEPTION_CODE)!
DLL Loaded: 77450000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll
Thread 5440 created, Entry: clr.6F96B510, Parameter: 00000000
Thread 4228 created, Entry: clr.6F8D1090, Parameter: 01843F78
DLL Loaded: 6E380000 C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\faf93f57aa8c4c5dddd9cd0de441d5a1\mscorlib.ni.dll
DLL Loaded: 765F0000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll
DLL Loaded: 76160000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll
DLL Loaded: 773E0000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll
DLL Loaded: 72900000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll
DLL Loaded: 71840000 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
DLL Loaded: 77680000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll
Thread 7844 created, Entry: clr.6F8D1090, Parameter: 0185C1D8
DLL Loaded: 71620000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wldp.dll
DLL Loaded: 71820000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\amsi.dll
DLL Loaded: 70CF0000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\userenv.dll
DLL Loaded: 75790000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll
DLL Loaded: 70C80000 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Platform\4.18.23090.2008-0\X86\MpOAV.dll
DLL Loaded: 70810000 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Platform\4.18.23090.2008-0\X86\MpClient.dll
DLL Loaded: 763F0000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll
DLL Loaded: 769F0000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll
DLL Loaded: 75880000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll
DLL Loaded: 757E0000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gpapi.dll
Thread 7464 created, Entry: ntdll.77ABCAC0, Parameter: 0189B5B8
DLL Loaded: 6D920000 C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\5c00af63074fbeb811ca3b6c1552ed20\System.ni.dll
DLL Loaded: 6D100000 C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Core\611f56c68c2c55b1d118f964dfdc6622\System.Core.ni.dll
DLL Loaded: 70700000 C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\e029a233012f92553fe6423c55cab701\System.Configuration.ni.dll
DLL Loaded: 70410000 C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Drawing\5b458af6b683d9b9449f798de5c10835\System.Drawing.ni.dll
DLL Loaded: 6C290000 C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\daf04e26978e0023bf6e58858de15840\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll
DLL Loaded: 01AE0000 C:\Program Files (x86)\Leotronic Scales Pvt. Ltd\WeighPro\WeighProSQL.DLL
DLL Loaded: 05CF0000 C:\Program Files (x86)\Leotronic Scales Pvt. Ltd\WeighPro\WeighProSQL.DLL
DLL Unloaded: 01AE0000 weighprosql.dll
Thread 6500 created, Entry: combase.7628AF70, Parameter: 018BD240
Thread 8280 created, Entry: ntdll.77ABCAC0, Parameter: 0184F798
Thread 7840 created, Entry: ntdll.77ABCAC0, Parameter: 0184F798
DLL Loaded: 6BB10000 C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml\8942301a17f33b71c4ba78ae7eff3a07\System.Xml.ni.dll
DLL Loaded: 758D0000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll
DLL Loaded: 729A0000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\windows.storage.dll
Set hardware breakpoint on 777B6580!
DLL Loaded: 77720000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll
DLL Loaded: 75800000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll
DLL Loaded: 75860000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll
DLL Loaded: 75830000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll
DLL Loaded: 75820000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll
DLL Loaded: 70BF0000 C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.20348.1_none_6a9207a4854d1923\comctl32.dll
DLL Loaded: 6B9A0000 C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.20348.1787_none_0d12da645dfca258\GdiPlus.dll
DLL Loaded: 6B780000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DWrite.dll
Thread 6404 created, Entry: gdiplus.6BA167B0, Parameter: 06201408
DLL Loaded: 77530000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll
DLL Loaded: 72070000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\TextShaping.dll
EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO:
           dwFirstChance: 1
           ExceptionCode: E06D7363 (CPP_EH_EXCEPTION)
          ExceptionFlags: 00000001
        ExceptionAddress: kernelbase.76048D52
        NumberParameters: 3
ExceptionInformation[00]: 19930520
ExceptionInformation[01]: 014FD344
ExceptionInformation[02]: clr.6FFB0AE8
First chance exception on 76048D52 (E06D7363, CPP_EH_EXCEPTION)!
EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO:
           dwFirstChance: 1
           ExceptionCode: E06D7363 (CPP_EH_EXCEPTION)
          ExceptionFlags: 00000001
        ExceptionAddress: kernelbase.76048D52
        NumberParameters: 3
ExceptionInformation[00]: 19930520
ExceptionInformation[01]: 00000000
ExceptionInformation[02]: 00000000
First chance exception on 76048D52 (E06D7363, CPP_EH_EXCEPTION)!
DLL Loaded: 75150000 C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.20348.1_none_d0810af484aa16f0\comctl32.dll
Thread 3292 created, Entry: clr.6F8D1090, Parameter: 018B38D0
Thread 6080 created, Entry: clr.6F812E80, Parameter: 00000000
Thread 1032 created, Entry: clr.6F8D1090, Parameter: 0698DA20
DLL Loaded: 70940000 C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Serv759bfb78#\d413636e87f6d58ce36c6cc45cc291a4\System.ServiceProcess.ni.dll
DLL Loaded: 725D0000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\TextInputFramework.dll
DLL Loaded: 6B650000 C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Management\8fbafc2bfab952b673db08298710f689\System.Management.ni.dll
DLL Loaded: 706D0000 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WMINet_Utils.dll
DLL Loaded: 76890000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll
DLL Loaded: 706B0000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem\wmiutils.dll
DLL Loaded: 703A0000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbemcomn.dll
Thread 6080 exit
DLL Loaded: 70BE0000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem\wbemprox.dll
DLL Loaded: 70690000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem\wbemsvc.dll
DLL Loaded: 6B580000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem\fastprox.dll
EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO:
           dwFirstChance: 1
           ExceptionCode: C0000005 (EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
          ExceptionFlags: 00000000
        ExceptionAddress: 01A3D1BC
        NumberParameters: 2
ExceptionInformation[00]: 00000000 Read
ExceptionInformation[01]: 00000000 Inaccessible Address
First chance exception on 01A3D1BC (C0000005, EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)!
Thread 7844 exit
Thread 1032 exit
EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO:
           dwFirstChance: 1
           ExceptionCode: C0000005 (EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
          ExceptionFlags: 00000000
        ExceptionAddress: 01A3D1BC
        NumberParameters: 2
ExceptionInformation[00]: 00000000 Read
ExceptionInformation[01]: 00000000 Inaccessible Address
First chance exception on 01A3D1BC (C0000005, EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)!
EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO:
           dwFirstChance: 1
           ExceptionCode: E0434352 (CLR_EXCEPTION)
          ExceptionFlags: 00000001
        ExceptionAddress: kernelbase.76048D52
        NumberParameters: 5
ExceptionInformation[00]: 80070002
ExceptionInformation[01]: 00000000
ExceptionInformation[02]: 00000000
ExceptionInformation[03]: 00000000
ExceptionInformation[04]: clr.6F7E0000
First chance exception on 76048D52 (E0434352, CLR_EXCEPTION)!
DebugString: "RegistrationThread-3 has started."
DebugString: "RegistrationThread-3 has started."
Thread 4620 created, Entry: clr.6F8D1090, Parameter: 0698BEC8
Thread 6972 created, Entry: clr.6F8D1090, Parameter: 069967D8
Thread 8392 created, Entry: clr.6F812E80, Parameter: 00000000
EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO:
           dwFirstChance: 1
           ExceptionCode: C0000005 (EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
          ExceptionFlags: 00000000
        ExceptionAddress: 01A3D1BC
        NumberParameters: 2
ExceptionInformation[00]: 00000000 Read
ExceptionInformation[01]: 00000000 Inaccessible Address
First chance exception on 01A3D1BC (C0000005, EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)!
Thread 8392 exit
EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO:
           dwFirstChance: 1
           ExceptionCode: C0000005 (EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
          ExceptionFlags: 00000000
        ExceptionAddress: 01A3D1BC
        NumberParameters: 2
ExceptionInformation[00]: 00000000 Read
ExceptionInformation[01]: 00000000 Inaccessible Address
First chance exception on 01A3D1BC (C0000005, EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)!
Thread 3292 exit
Thread 6972 exit
DLL Loaded: 72500000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreMessaging.dll
DLL Loaded: 72270000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreUIComponents.dll
Thread 5932 created, Entry: ntdll.77ABCAC0, Parameter: 017E0880
Thread 5524 created, Entry: ntdll.77ABCAC0, Parameter: 017E0880
```

[image: Here's the picture of the registration window, and some of the windows api calls it makes]

**Update**:

So I took, @0xC0000022L's advice and used `dnspy` to decompile the .exe. It was a life saver, and I was able to extract the class that's responsible for registration. Only issue is, there are calls that are obfuscated. It apparently uses `confuser` and `confuserex` (as per `die`) for obfuscating these calls. Can these calls be deobfuscated somehow? I couldn't anything useful on youtube, it's just skiddies there.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. Other than the screenshot and some vague wording, how do you imagine anyone will be able to deduce any details about the program you are looking at? Where does Ghidra or x64dbg (both tagged) come in? Please edit your question to add more details so anyone who doesn't sit in front of _your_ computer would be able to fill in the (hopefully few) remaining blanks. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the vague Information. I've edited it. I hope this will do.

Comment: That looks a little better already. Thanks. Without the binary, I doubt there is much other than generic advice that can be given here. It looks like it's a .NET program, which first of all means that ILSpy and similar programs are likely better suited to help here. WinDbg also generally has good support for .NET/CLR programs; for x64dbg I have no experience with .NET. A DLL placement attack with a manipulated `mscoree.dll` may be a nice way to intercept more stuff from _within_ the process. If those are Windows Forms, you could try a window hook to trigger a break point on button click.

Comment: Another thing to run would be Detect-It-Easy (DIE) to scan for known obfuscators and/or runtime packers. The absence of string matches suggests that such techniques could have been employed in creation of the `.exe` in question.

Comment: Hey @0xC0000022L, thanks for all this information. It gives me some stepping stones to begin with. Here's the link to the program, if you wanna check it out yourself, easyupload.io/lwpk01.